# (c/c++) dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss to unix timestamp

Tags: c, time, arduino, unix-timestamp

given a date string `dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss`, we wish to convert it to a unix timestamp (10 digits) through a function.

```
long foo(int yyyy, int mm = 0, int dd = 0, int hh = 0, int ii = 0, int ss = 0) { }
```

i couldn't figure out the exact formula that gives accurate results, ones that match [unixtimestamp.com](http://unixtimestamp.com).

> Unix time is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds.

Comment: What do you mean, you didn't find out the exact formula? You can parse the string and put the data in a `struct tm`. The [`mktime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html) function will give you a `time_t`, which is a valid Unix timestamp. You can even defer the parsing to [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html).

Comment: @DieterLücking `strftime()` won't do me any good, it gives back a string that is based on a given unix timestamp, i am looking for the opposite, the output is a long integer, for example `1446288870`

Comment: @user5470921 You should note there isn't a language like C/C++. I can't see anything C++ relevant in your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the code needed is in either c or c++, how is that not relevant?

Comment: @MOehm by formula i meant what's inside `mktime()` (which i wasn't aware exists in c++ untill now), i'll give it it shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on arduino using the time library [github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time](http://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time)

```
#include <Time.h>

struct unix {
  long get(int y, int m = 0, int d = 0, int h = 0, int i = 0, int s = 0) {
    setTime(h, i, s, d, m, y);
    adjustTime(-10800); // +3
    return now();
  }
} unix;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.setTimeout(0);

  Serial.println("..");
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015));
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015, 10));
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015, 10, 31));
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015, 10, 31, 18));
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015, 10, 31, 18, 41));
  //Serial.println(unix.get(2015, 10, 31, 18, 41, 0));

  Serial.println("Enter the date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss am/pm). Example: \"31/10/2015 7:27 pm\".");
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int dd = Serial.readStringUntil('/').toInt();
    int mm = Serial.readStringUntil('/').toInt();
    int yyyy = Serial.readStringUntil(' ').toInt();
    int hh = Serial.readStringUntil(':').toInt();
    int ii = Serial.readStringUntil(':').toInt();
    int ss = Serial.readStringUntil(' ').toInt();
    String pm = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

    if (pm == 0) pm = "am";
    Serial.print(dd); Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(mm); Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(yyyy); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(hh); Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(ii); Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(ss); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(pm); Serial.print(" = ");

    if (pm == "pm") hh += 12;
    Serial.println(unix.get(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, ii, ss));
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("Enter the date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss am/pm).");
  }

  delay(50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `strptime` can do the parsing for you to create a `struct tm`.  Then you can call `mktime` to get a `time_t`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{
    struct tm mytm;
    time_t t;
    strptime("31/10/2015 08:33:00","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",&mytm);
    t = mktime(&mytm);
    printf("t=%ld\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
t=1446294780
```

Comment: great! i utilized this for usage on an arduino.

Comment: @user5470921 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tm struct (from < time.h>/< ctime>) and passing those parameters to it, then you can simple call the mktime() funtion or the timegm() funtion, which depends on you want to take the input as local time or GMT time.

One thing you should carefully remember is that the actual year stored in tm struct is (year-1990), and month should be (month-1). Don't forget to set the tm's tm_isdst flag. You can set is as -1 which can automatically detect whether daylight saving time is applied.

For example, you want to convert GMT 11/02/1990 00:16:50.

```
tm* t;
t->tm_sec = 50;
t->tm_min = 16;
t->tm_hour = 0;
t->tm_mday = 11;
t->tm_mon = 1; // 2-1, not 2!
t->tm_year = 90; // 1990-1900, not 1990!
t->tm_isdst = -1;
```

Then you can call timegm(t) which will give you the result 634695410.